# Como detectar a colisão entre dois quadrados/retângulos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Quem fornecer uma resposta que explique todas as nuances necessárias para tal em javascript ganhará os pontos.

Comment: Se você não entendeu o código de um usuário, você deveria ter postado comentários lá na pergunta original solicitando esclarecimentos dele (afinal, ninguém melhor do que o autor para explicar o que foi feito). Ou seja, abrir uma nova pergunta não é o caminho pra isso neste site. Eu só não voto pra fechar como duplicada (ou, até mesmo, fora do escopo) por causa da recompensa ativa.

Comment: Oi Luiz muito obrigado pelas dicas e observações, quanto ao usuário do outro post sou eu mesmo, inclusive requisitei que o autor do algoritmo da solução fizesse comentário no próprio código e que também esclarecesse um trecho do código, o comentário no código ele fez, mas a pergunta do trecho do código ele não respondeu, depois disso apaguei o post que eu mesmo havia postado perguntando. Um outro detalhe Luiz se você me permite é que apesar da semelhança do título  o algoritmo será diferente pois os objetivos são outros apesar da semelhança.

Comment: Por último se eu fosse inteligente como você é Luiz, eu poderia ter entendido desde a primeira vez e claramente a lógica que ele fez e o trecho da codificação.

Comment: Obrigado pelo elogio, mas não acho que é uma questão de ser mais ou menos inteligente. Se esse é outro problema e será mesmo diferente, é mais um motivo pra não ter ligação com o código original (porque assim você não enviesa a solução desse problema). Sobre o que você mencionou do outro colega não ter te respondido, você poderia ter colocado a recompensa naquela mesma pergunta se a sua questão era entendimento. Enfim, só estou argumentando que do jeito que a pergunta está ela é complicada, porque [este site não é um fórum](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2068/73). Mas, boa sorte! :)

Comment: Vamos fazer o que é correto então Luiz, você me ajuda a fazer da maneira correta? O que preciso mudar para que a pergunta fique mais simples? fechamos esse post e refazemos o outro post?

Comment: Pra começar, no futuro procure ser mais pragmático. Sobre a sua dúvida, no título vc diz "detecção de colisão". Aí, na sua pergunta original, perguntou sobre "alinhamento a esquerda" e nessa sobre "alinhamento acima". Vc percebe que está fazendo a pergunta sobre a sua ideia de solução, ao invés de perguntar sobre o real problema (que é a detecção de colisão)? Leia depois sobre o [Problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy).

Comment: Pra essa questão, e pra aproveitar a sua recompensa, eu sugeriria perguntar diretamente "Como detectar a colisão entre dois quadrados/retângulos". Quem fornecer uma resposta que explique *todas* as nuances necessárias para tal, conforme você julgar apropriado, é pra quem você concede a recompensa. É melhor do que ir perguntando por partes com base em "alinhamento" (que não é exatamente o conceito ideal para o que parece que você quer fazer).

Comment: Até fiz uma resposta aqui simulando dois retângulos como paredes e uma caixa que bate em casa uma mudando a direção na hora da colisão, mas a explicação ta meio ruim então não vou postar. =P

Comment: Olá @Ack você lembra daquele jogo Tetris onde formas geométricas diferentes vão descendo para base para serem encaixadas? Gostaria de entender justamente aquele princípio, quando um quadrado encosta em outro e ele para de se mover, pois gostaria de enviar múltiplos quadrados para cima (um quadrado de cada vez) e quando ele encostar em outro ele parar de se mover.

Comment: @user31050 a pergunta por si só está clara, mas quando li sobre o princípio do Tetris é que vi realmente que entendi o que você quer, vou dar uma pesquisada e tentar formar algo, se ficar claro e conseguir explicar bem posto aqui.

Comment: @Mathias blz Mathias, respondi seu post sobre o click no input.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para mostrar como funciona a detecção de colisão entre dois objetos vou utilizar duas `div's` quadradas em um plano **2D**, mas a detecção de colisão pode ser aplicada para qualquer forma de objeto, desde que tenhamos as dimensões dos objetos em questão e esse conceito serve também para planos em **3D**, a diferença do 2D para o 3D é que em 3D trabalhamos com três dimensões (x,y,z) enquanto no 2D são apenas duas (x,y), o que torna o processo bem mais simples.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Os dois objetos(div's) vão possuir as seguintes dimensões, a primeira `div`(azul) possui 100px de altura e 100px de largura, a segunda `div`(vermelha) possui a metade do tamanho da primeira, logo 50px de altura e 50px de largura.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Posição

Para conseguir a posição do elemento temos duas opções `.position()` ou `.offset()`, o método `.position()` retorna a localização relativa ao ancestral mais próximo, enquanto o `.offset()` retorna a posição em relação ao documento. Não explicarei a fundo os métodos se quiser entender mais sobre eles [clique aqui](https://api.jquery.com/position/), no exemplo em questão não faz diferença pois o elemento pai ou ancestral é o próprio documento.

### Colisão

A colisão nesse contexto que criamos, considerando somente estes dois elementos, vai acontecer quando as seguintes condições forem verdadeiras:

**Na horizontal:**

Quando a extremidade direita do elemento mais a esquerda(**A2**) for maior ou igual a extremidade esquerda do elemento mais a direita(**V1**) e menor ou igual a extremidade direita do elemento mais a direita(**V2**).

*V1<=A2<=V2*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Na vertical:**

Quando a extremidade de baixo do elemento mais acima(**A4**) for maior ou igual a extremidade de cima do elemento mais abaixo(**V3**) e menor ou igual a extremidade de baixo do elemento mais abaixo(**V4**).

*V3<=A4<=V4*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

### Extremidades

```
var posAzul = $(".azul").position();
A1 = posAzul.left;
A2 = posAzul.left + $(".azul").width();
A3 = posAzul.top;
A4 = posAzul.top + $(".azul").height();
```

Da mesma maneira conseguimos as extremidades do bloco vermelho.

Se essas duas condições forem satisfeitas simultaneamente podemos afirmar que houve colisão entre os objetos. Existem n formas de fazer essa verificação, segue um exemplo bem prático que verifica se há colisão entre dois objetos, espero que ajude.

```js
$("#dir").click(function() {
  $(".azul").animate({
    "left": "+=50px"
  }, "fast", checkCollisions);
});

$("#esq").click(function() {
  $(".azul").animate({
    "left": "-=50px"
  }, "fast", checkCollisions);
});

$("#cima").click(function() {
  $(".azul").animate({
    "top": "-=50px"
  }, "fast", checkCollisions);
});

$("#baixo").click(function() {
  $(".azul").animate({
    "top": "+=50px"
  }, "fast", checkCollisions);
});

function getPositions(vermelho) {
  var $vermelho = $(vermelho);
  var pos = $vermelho.position();
  var width = $vermelho.width();
  var height = $vermelho.height();
  return [
    [pos.left, pos.left + width],
    [pos.top, pos.top + height]
  ];
}

function comparePositions(p1, p2) {
  var x1 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p1 : p2;
  var x2 = p1[0] < p2[0] ? p2 : p1;
  return x1[1] > x2[0] || x1[0] === x2[0] ? true : false;
}

function checkCollisions() {
  var vermelho = $(".vermelho")[0];
  var pos = getPositions(vermelho);

  var pos2 = getPositions(this);
  var horizontalMatch = comparePositions(pos[0], pos2[0]);
  var verticalMatch = comparePositions(pos[1], pos2[1]);
  var match = horizontalMatch && verticalMatch;
  if (match) {
    $("body").append("<p>Colisão!</p>");
  }
}
```

```css
.azul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: blue;
  left: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 30px;
}

.vermelho {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  left: 300px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 30px;
  top: 70px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="cima" style="width:150px;">Cima</button>
<br>
<button id="esq" style="width:75px;">Esquerda</button>
<button id="dir" style="width:75px;">Direita</button>
<br>
<button id="baixo" style="width:150px;">Baixo</button>

<div class="azul"></div>
<div class="vermelho"></div>
```

Comment: @user31050 Olha esse fiddle que fiz alterando o código da primeira resposta do tópico que tu me mandou, isso que tu precisava? https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/crboo2hz/

Comment: @user31050 Razoavelmente foi simples, ao invés de alterar o .left de cada elemento, foi alterado o .top, compara os dois métodos que tu identifica com facilidade as mudanças.

Comment: @user31050 Posso te explicar sim, estou na rua no momento mas assim que possível deixo uma breve explicação.

Comment: @user31050 hahaha, desculpa cara to meio cheio de coisa no trabalho, estou em dívida contigo, vamos fazer o seguinte, tu tens o link do fiddle com o código, hoje ainda atualizo lá o código com a explicação em um comentário.

Comment: @user31050 https://jsfiddle.net/mathiasfcx/crboo2hz/7/

Comment: A linha 44 a 55 que fica difícil entender @Mathias, queria mesmo era saber aquela parte lá da lógica que ele fez.

Comment: @user31050 realmente, ali ta mais confuso, mas faz o seguinte, primeiro ignora os comentários que estão lá, eles estão se referindo ao algoritmo que movia para esquerda, segundo cria um .html no teu pc mesmo e da uma debugada naquele código, especificamente naquela parte da 44 a 55, ai talvez fique mais claro, ali são todas as verificações que ele faz p/ não haver colisão, aquela manipulação de arrays que deixa o negócio tenso kk.